# Maven Version - How to have different versions for different projects

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when I run mvn install for a project it starts running with maven version 3.3.9. When I try to delete this version, and run mvn install again, it automatically starts installing version 3.3.9. I want to run this project with Version 3.5.4 and there is one another project in my system and it's version is 3.9.4. I don't want to change the other projects version but this current one's. How can I do that?
In IntelliJ settings I have already selected the path to Maven home as the path to 3.5.4 version

I tried changing PATH and M2_HOME variables, yet no affect.

Comment: A quick google search got me this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven2_install. you have an option in IntelliJ to set project level maven version.

Comment: I have developed the plugin for Intellij pursuing such goal: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21061-mvntermenv

Comment: What is the reason you want version 3.5.4 of Maven? Why not take a new version like 3.8.7 or 3.9.5 ?

Comment: Use the most recent versions as @JFabianMeier already mentioned.. If project using such old versions that sounds wrong..

Comment: i tried doing that and it worked, thanks a lot. actually while running mvn commands it was showing that it requires a specific version 3.5.4 thus i was trying for this specific version.

Comment: also, in my pom.xml file version of maven is 3.3.9 but when i execute mvn -version i get the result as 3.9.5, so does that mean system variables overwrites pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If you run commands from IDEA's [Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html) it will rely on OS-level settings (as in PATH Environmental Variable in Windows).

IDEA allows you to to choose which version of Maven to use in Maven settings (see [Maven Home Path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html)) either via `maven-wrapper.properties` file or by directly pointing to Maven binary that you would like to use. Those settings are per-Project, so you can use different versions of Maven for different Projects.

Those settings will be applied to Lifecycles/Goals you run from the [Maven Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) and [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html).

Hope this helps!